# Jackknife and matrix diagonalization

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues, jackknife

Suppose I have  $M$ matrices $n\times n$ of the form:
\begin{equation}
C^{k} = \begin{bmatrix}
    x^{k}_{11}      & x^{k}_{12} & x^{k}_{13} & \dots & x^{k}_{1n} \\
    x^{k}_{21}       & x^{k}_{22} & x^{k}_{23} & \dots & x^{k}_{2n} \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\    
    x^{k}_{n1}       & x^{k}_{n2} & x^{k}_{n3} & \dots & x^{k}_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $k = 1\ldots M$ and the $x^{k}_{ij}$ are the data at my disposal.
What I need from these matrices are the eigenvalues $\lambda^k_{i}$.

Now the data analysis I have to perform is made using the Jackknife method. My question is the following: Should I generate $M$ jackknife samples $C^{J}$ of the matrices, diagonalize these and then use the $\lambda^{J}$ to calculate the errors, the mean etc, or should I extract the eigenvalues first and then generate the jacknife samples from them? Are the two procedures any different?

Comment: Correct me if I've misunderstood something...  
You have M matrices, and M associated (leading) eigenvalues.  And you are asking whether it is equivalent to Jackknife over the matrices and then calculate the eigenvalues, versus jackknife over the eigenvalues?  It seems trivial to see that the resulting samples of the eigenvalues are identical.  Does this answer your question, or is there a subtlety that I fail to appreciate?

Comment: I have $M$ matrices with $n$ eigenvalues each, then the question is basically as you have stated it. I don't know if there are any subtelties, I am no expert on the subject. If the two are equivalent, then if you can prove it to me, there it is the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given M matrices, with N eigenvalues each, we want to perform a Jackknife procedure for the eigenvalues. Without loss of generality (i.e. we can generalize to the second-through-Nth eigenvalue), we will discuss the Jackknife procedure for the first (leading) eigenvalue.  The Jackknife procedure involves looking at the distribution of estimates of the mean eigenvalue over the M separate M-1 sized samples that each leave one matrix out.

A given sample contains the matrices 1,2,...,i-1, i+1,...,N (this sample leaves out the ith matrix). For any such sample, we calculate the eigenvalues of the associated matrices, yielding our jackknifed sample of eigenvalues 1,2,...,i-1,i+1,...,N.

Now imagine we instead calculated the eigenvalues first and then did the jackknifing.  We'd still get a sample that consists of eigenvalues 1,2,...,i-1,i+1,...,N.

Thus, the methods described in the OP and the comments are equivalent.